How to get sourcemapped stack from JavaScript Error object in the Browser?
When I create err = new Error("test-error") and console.log(err) I can see the stack mapped to the original sources using the sourcemap in the developer console.
But when I read the err.stack property I get a string which is not source-mapped. It shows files and line numbers from generated files.
How do I get the source-mapped stack from the err object?

I guess you'll have to load, parse and apply the source maps yourself for that. There is no method on error that handles them for you

If you want to programmatically access the source-mapped stack trace, you'll need to use libraries like stacktrace.js also
trackJS
